# Facebook applinks does not open Google Play when app not installed

Tags: android, facebook, google-play, applinks

I have an Android application with Facebook sharing, and also applinks and deep linking. If the user have my app installed, everything goes well. User clicks shared item and my app opens.

**However when my APP is not installed, the news feed just open the shared link with Facebook app browser. But I want that the news feed shared from the my APP can send people to the APP's Google Play page. Can anyone give me some hints? **

I've read the Applinks section from Facebook below: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/android

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have available web content? If you do, then this is the expected behavior. Why would you force someone to install an app before they can see your content?

Comment: yes, I have web content. It is not appropriate user to install app. Facebook iOS app shows  button to open App Store  but Facebook Android app does not showing install app button for same web page.

Comment: You can file a bug at developers.facebook.com/bugs